# Passing Value from URL using RenderPartial to another View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a View which uses @Html.RenderPartial for showing some data which is present on another View.

I want to send an ID present in the URL into the RenderPartial so that it can be utilized on the Other Page.

Following is my code of **JobView.cshtml** which uses **@Html.RenderPartial**:

```
@model NurseOneStop.SC.PostedJob

@{
ViewBag.Title = "JobView";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}


<div class="row">
<div class="lstCard">
    <div class="applied-view">
        <p>
            <b>Job Salary:</b> @Model.JobSalary
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Job Desc:</b> @Model.JobDesc
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Job Summary:</b> @Model.JobSummary
        </p>

        <p>
            <b>Job Application Type:</b> @Model.JobApplicationType
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>CategoryId:</b> @Model.Category
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Number Of Positions:</b> @Model.NumberOfPositions
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>CreatedOn:</b> @Model.CreatedOn.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Skills:</b> @Model.SkillNames
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Status:</b> @if (Model.Status)
            {
                <span>Open</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>Class</span>
            }
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="lstCard">
        <h2>Applied Nurses List</h2>
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("NurseListView", (List<NurseOneStop.SC.NurseProfile>)Model.AppliedNurses, new ViewDataDictionary { { "PostedJobId", Model.PostedJobId } });

    }
</div>
</div>
<p class="back-tolist">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Below is my code for **NurseListView.cshtml**:

```
@model IEnumerable<NurseOneStop.SC.NurseProfile>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <span><b style="color:#007976; font-weight:600;">@item.Title&nbsp;@item.FirstName&nbsp;@item.LastName</b></span><br />
    <span><b>Profession:</b> @item.Profession</span><br />
    <span><b>Mobile:</b> @item.PhoneNumber</span><br />
    <span><b>Email:</b> @item.EmailId</span><br />
    <span><b>Verified Email:</b> @(item.IsVerifiedEmail ? "Yes" : "No")</span><br />
    <span><b>Verified Contact:</b> @(item.IsVerifiedContact ? "Yes" : "No")</span><br />
    <span><b>Applied On:</b> @item.CreatedOn.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</span><br />
    <span><b>Skills:</b> @item.Skills</span><br />
    <span><b>Address:</b> @item.AddressLine1,&nbsp;@item.AddressLine2&nbsp;@item.ZipCode</span><br />
    @*<span>@item.ProfileUrl</span>*@
    <span>@item.CurrentPosition</span><br />
    <span>@item.Summary</span><br />
    <span>@item.PreferredJobLocation</span>
    <p class="no-margin" style="text-align:right">
        @Html.ActionLink("Download CV", "DownloadResume", "PostedJob", new { ResumeId = item.NurseResumeList[0].ResumeId , PostedJobId = item.PostedJobId}, new { @class = "btnViewJobDetails" })
        <a href="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Website"]+"/nurse/NurseView?NurseId=" + item.NurseId)" class="btnViewJobDetails">View Profile</a>
        @Html.ActionLink("Message", "SendMessage", "Recruiter", new { NurseId = item.NurseId }, new { @class = "btnViewJobDetails" })
    </p>
</div>
}
```

http://localhost:49509/PostedJob/JobView?PostedJobId=100162&returnUrl=%2FPostedJob%2FIndex

I want to pass **PostedJobId** which is shown in the URL on the click of **Download CV** option.

How to do that?

Comment: `model.PostedJobId = Request.QueryString["PostedJobId"]` in GET action may be fine, assumed you're returning `PostedJob` with `return View(model)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["PostedJobId"]` in your partial view to access `PostedJobId` value from URL.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download CV", "DownloadResume", "PostedJob", new { ResumeId = item.NurseResumeList[0].ResumeId , PostedJobId = Request.QueryString["PostedJobId"]}, new { @class = "btnViewJobDetails" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download CV", "DownloadResume", "PostedJob", new { ResumeId = item.NurseResumeList[0].ResumeId , PostedJobId = Request.QueryString["PostedJobId"]}, new { @class = "btnViewJobDetails" })
```

Comment: this is not good that you just copied my answer and paste it to your